# Example of convex activation function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, activation-function

For a particular task, I need a convex activation function with the following properties:

- f''(x) > 0
- 0 <=    f(x) <=  1
- f(x) is monotonic
- f(x) is not "exploding" i.e. avoiding functions such as f(x) = x²

The only example I have in mind for this is the softplus activation function. Would you have anything else in mind?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such function.

A convex function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ with bounded range [is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/518091/493872).

Softplus is not bounded above as required by your second bullet.